# Moving animation keyframes breaks all

Tags: animation, keyframes, pose-mode, timeline

When I want to move a group of keyframes the entire sequence breaks
How should I move them?
[image]

Comment: Hello, what are your trying to achieve? If you want the whole armature to move, only move the curve of the root bone (or the bone that is at the top of the hierarchy)

Comment: Hi, I want to move keyframes to the right for having more space between keyframes. But when I do that the sequence brokes

Comment: I see the problem. I had to select all armature before moving the keyframes. Thanks for the help

Comment: Oh OK then   ;)   ............